# Javascript to get information dropdown lists and apply condition

Tags: javascript

I need to know how I can get information selected in a dropdown list when I press submit and then get the information displayed in a table within the same page.

I have created the dropdown list:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Please let me know how to display if for instance I select Volvo to be displayed within a td:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/603003) for a start.

Comment: How familiar are you with [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM)? And, what of that have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't really the right place to ask for a complete solution. If you're wondering how to get started, we can offer some suggestions. Or, if you can share an attempt you've made, we can try to assist with that.

Comment: @ComFreek I have read those but how can I then get the data to display in a td? Thanks

Comment: skip the js, learn how html works first

Comment: jQuery okay, or just javascript?

Comment: @Tommy Reference the td cell (e.g. by calling getElementById()), then set its *innerHTML* property. This is the easiest way.

Comment: @ComFreek thanks I'll google that, not familiar with Javascript just trying to create a personal organiser to organise my projects.

Comment: How does this use php? This is all JavaScript DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Vulpus was thinking of using PHP if I couldnt do it with Javascript

Comment: @Tommy Your site runs on the client side. PHP runs on your server, therefore you can't do anything "live"/"dynamic" on your site using PHP (not involving AJAX or the like). You would have to do a site reload in order to fill in the values using PHP.

Comment: html form> echo post\get variable, no js needed

Comment: @ComFreek that's an *extremely* limited view of what "live"/"dynamic"  means

Comment: @Dagon I just wanted to express it simple enough for understanding it as a beginner. (I added *(Not involving AJAX)*, the comment should be correct, now.)

Comment: @Tommy PHP is server-side which means that all computation happens on the server while JavaScript is client-side. That means that all commutation happens on the visitor's computer

Comment: @Dagon I would have just used HTML but I will need certain things to appear depending on what has been selected for this. So your advice is void!

Comment: nothing in the question said, with out a page reload, psychic i am not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your elements a unique ID attribute and it is very easy to do this:

[Working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjwzs/)

**HTML:**

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="tr-1">
        <td id="td-1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Click Me">
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('mybutt').onclick = function() {
    var selcar = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
    //alert(selcar);
    document.getElementById('td-1').innerHTML = selcar;
};
```